# Common Lispで、#.を使って値の埋め込みをしたい

Tags: common-lisp, lisp, sbcl

SBCLでライブラリを作っています。

原始的な例ですが、test.lispの中に

```
(defparameter default-data
    #.(let ((size 10))
        (make-array size :initial-contents (alexandria:iota size))))
```

のように書くと、コンパイルする時――例えば`(asdf:load-system :test-system)`を実行したとき――に`#.`以降の部分を評価して、faslファイルには結果のarrayのみを埋め込んでくれる、つまり、test.faslをライブラリとしてロードする際にいちいち再計算されない、という理解をしています。

これを活用したいのですが、次の似た例ではうまくいきません。

```
(defun test-func (size)
    (make-array size :initial-contents (alexandria:iota size)))

(defparameter default-data #.(test-func 10))

; caught ERROR:
;   READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
;   
;     The function TEST-SYSTEM::TEST-FUNC is undefined.
```

こうなるのは、コンパイル時には`(defun test-func ...)`がまだ評価されていないからだ、という理解でいます。しかし、実際にこういう問題をどう解決すればいいのかわかりません。

上の例では`test-func`を`(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute) ...)`で括れば解決するようですが、自分のコードでは`test-func`がまた別のライブラリ内の関数を呼び……という構造になっています。それらの定義もすべて`eval-when`で括ると、1/3くらいは`eval-when`で括り、残りはいらない……というような見た目になります。それだったら、`eval-when`が必要な関数や変数を、最初にほうにまとめて括り、残りはいらない、という風にすべきかも……でも、ライブラリ内の種々のルーチンのまとまり、つながりから考えるに、それとは別の順番にしたほうがずっとわかりやすい……いっそのこと、全部の定義をまとめて`eval-when`で括る手もあるけれど、それはそれで不要な処理をしている気がするし……という風に悩んでいます。

こういったことに、もっとスマートな解決策はあるでしょうか？　それとも、すべては解決できないので、上で考えた選択肢のどれかを取るしかないでしょうか？

## 追記

g000001さんの

> defunをできるだけ先に評価しようとして、eval-whenを付けて、最も早い評価タイミングにしたとしても、コンパイル時までになりますのでやはり手遅れ、というのが起きている現象です。

という指摘が自分の経験則（？）とは違っていて不思議に思ったので、調べていたのですが、より謎が深まりました……

date.lisp その1 (単に`#.`を使う):

```
(defun get-date ()
  (multiple-value-bind (second minute hour date month year)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (prin1 "get-date called.")
    (format nil "~A/~A/~A ~A:~A:~A" year month date hour minute second)))

(defparameter date-string #.(get-date))
```

コンパイル:

```
C:\Users...> echo %date% %time% & sbcl --eval "(compile-file \"date.lisp\")"
2017/12/11 19:40:59.25
; caught ERROR:
;   READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
;
;     The function COMMON-LISP-USER::GET-DATE is undefined.
```

コンパイルエラーが出る。`#.`以降を評価する時点では`defun`が評価されていないのだから、これはわかります。

date.lisp その2（`#.`を使い、`eval-when`で括る）:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel)
  (defun get-date ()
    (multiple-value-bind (second minute hour date month year)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (prin1 "get-date called.")
    (format nil "~A/~A/~A ~A:~A:~A" year month date hour minute second))))

(defparameter date-string #.(get-date))
```

コンパイル:

```
C:\Users...>echo %date% %time% & sbcl --eval "(compile-file \"date.lisp\")"
2017/12/11 19:47:01.35
; コンパイル中
get-date called.
; コンパイル成功
CL-USER> (load "date.fasl")
CL-USER> date-string
"2017/12/11 19:47:1"  ; コンパイル時の時刻と同じ。
```

SBCL(1.3.18, Win64)では`eval-when`を付ければ手遅れではないように見えます（`#.`以降を評価する時点で、SBCLは既に`get-date`を知っている）。これはSBCL独自の仕様ということなのでしょうか？

date.lisp その3 (`#.`ではなく`load-time-value`を使う):

```
(defun get-date ()
  (multiple-value-bind (second minute hour date month year)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (prin1 "get-date called.")
    (format nil "~A/~A/~A ~A:~A:~A" year month date hour minute second)))

(defparameter date-string (load-time-value (get-date)))
```

コンパイル:

```
C:\Users...>echo %date% %time% & sbcl --eval "(compile-file \"date.lisp\")"
2017/12/11 19:51:45.33
; コンパイル成功
CL-USER> (load "date.fasl")
get-date called.
CL-USER> date-string
"2017/12/11 19:51:55"  ; コンパイル時の時刻ではない
```

date.faslをロードしたときに、`get-date`が呼ばれて`date-string`の値が決定する……という動作に見えます。

date.lisp その4（`load-time-value`を使い、`eval-when`で括る）:

```
(eval-when (:load-toplevel :compile-toplevel)
  (defun get-date ()
    (multiple-value-bind (second minute hour date month year)
      (get-decoded-time)
    (prin1 "get-date called.")
    (format nil "~A/~A/~A ~A:~A:~A" year month date hour minute second))))

(defparameter date-string (load-time-value (get-date)))
```

コンパイル:

```
C:\Users...>echo %date% %time% & sbcl --eval "(compile-file \"date.lisp\")"
2017/12/11 19:58:09.98
; コンパイル成功
CL-USER> (load "date.fasl")
get-date called.
CL-USER> date-string
"2017/12/11 19:58:14"  ; コンパイル時の時刻ではない
```

`eval-when`を付けない場合と同じです。

`load-time-value`の働き自体は[Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_ld_tim.htm)を読んでなんとなく把握したのですが、g000001さんの例にeval-whenがある理由（date.lispの例ならその３とその４の違い）がわかりません。

以上、大きくまとめて、２つの疑問が残っています。

1. g000001さんの指摘:

   > defunをできるだけ先に評価しようとして、eval-whenを付けて、最も早い評価タイミングにしたとしても、コンパイル時までになりますのでやはり手遅れ、というのが起きている現象です。

が手遅れではないように見える、という疑問。

2. `load-time-value`を使う場合、eval-whenで括っても括らなくても、動作に特に違いが無いように見える、という疑問。

Comment: (1) #.(test-func 10)の印象が強かったので、 > 上の例ではtest-funcを(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute) ...)で括れば解決する というのを(eval-when ... (test-func 10))と思って回答したのですが、test-funcを括っても、というところをdefunと書いていましたので回答を修正しました。混乱させてしまいすいません

(2) 私の回答コードでのload-time-valueの評価順は上から下とは限らず処理系依存です。
http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_ld_tim.htm
"but the order of evaluation with respect to the evaluation of top level forms in the file is implementation-dependent. "
ですので、処理系によっては、test-funcが未定義なこともあり得ます(実際cmuclではそうなります

Comment: ・ eval-whenについて|
eval-whenが多すぎる、ということならば、ファイルを分割して依存順にコンパイル/ロードして回避することが多いと思います。
もし質問の主題がそうならば、質問の題名を、「多過ぎるeval-whenを減らしたい」等に変更した方が良いと思います。

・ load-time-valueについて|
load-time-valueと#.の効果は等価ではありませんので、使い分けになります。
今回の配列を固定するコードの場合は、load-time-valueの方が適切ではないかと思います。

・ #.について|
#.はリード時に作用するのですが、Common Lisp特有の問題を引き起しがちなので、(処理系標準の機能だけを使って)定数を生成する等限定された使い方をすることが殆どです。

Comment: いろいろ謎が解けました。もちろんeval-whenは少ないほうが良いのですが、必ずしもその点のみを質問したかったわけではないというか、.faslに事前に計算した値を埋め込むような処理は、どうするのが定番なのだろうという疑問でした。

Comment: そもそも最初の例の変数をdefparameterではなくdefconstantにしたほうが質問の意味がはっきりしたかもし‌​れません。文脈がわかりにくい質問で申し訳なかったです。一応、やり取りで明らかになったと思うので、大きな不都合がなければこのままにしておきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、`#.`はリード時に作用するものなので、コンパイル時に作用するものではありません。  
リード時はコンパイル時より先に来ます。  
`test-func`をできるだけ先に評価しようとして、`eval-when`を付けて、最も早い評価タイミングにしたとしても、コンパイル時までになりますのでやはり手遅れ、というのが起きている現象です。

通常、上記のようなコードは、ロード時(書き出したfaslを読み込むタイミング)までに値が決定していれば良いことが殆どです。  
ですので、下記のようにロード時に値が固定するような`load-time-value`というフォームを使うことが多いです。

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel)
  (defun test-func (size)
    (make-array size :initial-contents (alexandria:iota size))))

(defparameter *default-data* 
  (load-time-value (test-func 10)))
```

Comment: eval-whenについて追記しました。

Comment: #.(test-func 10)の印象が強かったので、
> 上の例ではtest-funcを(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute) ...)で括れば解決する
というのを(eval-when ... (test-func 10))と思って回答したのですが、test-funcを括っても、というところをdefunと書いていましたので回答を修正しました。混乱させてしまいすいません

Comment: 謎が解けました、ありがとうございます。追記はそのままにしておきます。

Comment: eval-whenが多すぎる、ということならば、ファイルを分割して依存順にコンパイル/ロードして回避することが多いと思い‌​ます。 もし質問の主題がそうならば、質問の題名を、「多過ぎるeval-whenを減らしたい」等に変更した方が良いと思います。